# Import .sql file into multiple databases

Tags: mysql

How to import `.sql` file into multiple databases at one shot.

I have tried this:

```
mysql -uroot -p -all-databases < test.sql
```

But it asks for database name. Whatever there in `test.sql` file should reflect in all the databases/Schemas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running on Linux/Unix, you can do it with a bit of shell:

```
for DB in `mysql -u root -r --silent -p -e 'show databases;' | egrep -v "_schema$|^mysql$|^sys$"`
do 
  mysql -uroot -p $DB < test.sql
done
```

Will obviously be easier if you temporarily set it up to be passwordless.

Answer (score 2):

Export:
`sudo mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > mydatabases.sql`

Import (with names):
`sudo mysql -u root -p < mydatabases.sql`

Note that the database names are saved to dump/exported file. Meaning: the database names will be created if you use the `mysqldump` statement above. You do not need anything fancy on the restore statement. You do NOT specifiy a database name in this case - just the file redirect.

(Tested under: Ver 5.1.73-0ubuntu0.10.04.1 through Ver 5.7.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)

See also:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497869/export-and-import-all-mysql-databases-at-one-time